# How can I add a thumbnail image to a Bing Map pushpin's popup/flyout window?

Tags: html, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

I'm not certain about the terminology for the little window that pops out when you click a map marker/pushpin, but what I want to do with my Bing Map pushpin in this transitory window is display something like this when it is clicked/tapped:

```
My Dog Spot - miPerroMancha.png
{ the thumbnail here }
5/29/2013

elAmadoDeFresno.png
{ the thumbnail here }
10/19/2014
```

IOW, the "popup" should display:

```
The image description, if available, plus file name; otherwise, just the file name, 
The thumbnail version of the photo
The date the photo was taken
```

The marker will be pinned to the map at the location the photo was taken

The code I've got so far appears below. *photraxMap* is the name of the Bing Map; *pbd* is a class that contains information about the photo represented by the pushpin:

```
String fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(pbd.filePath);
Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
if (null == pbd.imgDescription)
{
    pushpin.Text = fileNameOnly;
}
else
{
    pushpin.Text = String.Format("{0} - {1}", pbd.imgDescription, fileNameOnly);
}
MapLayer.SetPosition(pushpin, new Location(pbd.latitude, pbd.longitude));
photraxMap.Children.Add(pushpin);
```

So the text will be the same as what I want to appear first on the flyout/popup.

Surely there's a way to tap into what displays when the pushpin is pushed/clicked/tapped, but how? Intellisense didn't show me anything obvious that way. I am hoping the pushpin has some property to which I can assign HTML. Am I looking in the right direction, or barking up the wrong tree?

### UPDATE

If this is not possible, then maybe what I need is a popup (or an "untethered flyout") that has noting directly to do with the Bing Map, but is invoked as a result of clicking the pushpin, and which will popup from that spot (with the upper-left corner of the popup/untethered flyout in the middle of the pushpin)

### UPDATE 2

I worked through your article blog. It seems to work a treat, except for one thing: the infobox that pops up is dark gray and shows no data:

[image]

I did change the code a little, using a String and a DateTime instead of two strings:

```
// The next few methods derived from http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/infoboxes-for-native-windows-store-apps/
private void CloseInfobox_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Infobox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

// Does an inline class make the most sense here?
public class PushpinMetadata
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeTaken { get; set; }
    // TODO: Add a Bitmap for the Thumbnail
}

// TODO: Add the Bitmap/Thumbnail to the args and the class
public void AddPushpin(Location latlong, string fileName, DateTime dateTimeTaken,  MapLayer layer)
{
    Pushpin p = new Pushpin()
    {
        Tag = new PushpinMetadata()
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            DateTimeTaken = dateTimeTaken // add Thumbnail = thumbnail
        }
    };

    MapLayer.SetPosition(p, latlong);

    p.Tapped += PinTapped;

    layer.Children.Add(p);
}

private void PinTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Pushpin p = sender as Pushpin;
    PushpinMetadata m = (PushpinMetadata)p.Tag;

    //Ensure there is content to be displayed before modifying the infobox control
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.FileName) || (null != m.DateTimeTaken))
    {
        Infobox.DataContext = m;

        Infobox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        MapLayer.SetPosition(Infobox, MapLayer.GetPosition(p));
    }
    else
    {
        Infobox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Do I need to stick with two Strings, passing DateTime.ToString()? Or is there some other problem?

### UPDATE 3

My bad - it was the XAML that I had failed to updated; I changed the names of the members of the class, and forgot to change the Binding statements in the XAML. Now it works (except for the bitmap - still don't know how to squeeze it into there / convert it from a byte array to a BitmapImage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create an infobox (tooltip), that shows a panel above your pushpin and contains some information. This is fairly easy to do and is something I have written about many times in blogs and in my book. Here is a blog post on to do this: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/infoboxes-for-native-windows-store-apps/

You might also be interested in my free ebook on creating location intelligent Windows Store apps. You can download a copy of it here: http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/

Comment: I'm going to czech all this out when I get home, but I'm wondering if (you say infobox/tooltip) it would be advisable to use a Flyout for this? I would think one could respond to a click/tap on the marker, and then position a Flyout at that spot...?

Comment: See Update 3, too (it was my bad - it works now). Even though your answer didn't directly answer my question, it helped me a ton (or tonne in your neck of the woods) and I will bountify it ASAP.

Comment: Even though I'm based in the UK I'm actually Canadian and grew up on a border city with the US, so ton or tonne both work fine for me :)

Comment: Also, take a look at this blog on how to convert byte[] to BitmapImage: http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/04/convert-byte-array-to-an-image-in-winrt

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'll get on that when I get home from work.

Comment: It looked very promising, but unfortunately, it won't compile. I get "'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'AsBuffer'" on this line: await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer()); I left a comment about it there, but it has not shown up.

Comment: Maybe this, from "Windows Store Apps Succinctly" is a clue:
*Buffers/byte arrays—System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime. WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions: Extension methods in this class provide ways for moving between .NET byte arrays and the contents of WinRT buffers, exposed as IBuffer implementations.*

...but if it is, that's not enough info for me to know what to do with it. Instead of "TMI" it's "NEI" (Not Enough Information).