# Why are my BitmapImages not displaying?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, bing-maps, bitmapimage

Ad[a,o]pting Brundritt's example [here](http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/infoboxes-for-native-windows-store-apps/), which he referenced in responding to [my earlier BingMaps question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458697/how-can-i-add-a-thumbnail-image-to-a-bing-map-pushpins-popup-flyout-window), I have been able to display certain data in an "infobox" like so:

[image]

...but am not getting the BitmapImage that is part of the data I intend to display.

My question is why are the images not displaying, and what do I need to go in order to display them?

It's not the data - I've saved the thumbnail image to a SQLite database, where it is stored as an array of bytes, but which can be seen as images in [SQLiteToolbox](https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/):

[image: SQLiteToolbox]:

So as you can see, the String data is displaying fine, but not the image. Here is the pertinent code I've got for retrieving the data and displaying it:

```
// The class used to create the SQLite table
public class PhotraxBaseData
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    [SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    . . .
    public DateTime dateTimeTaken { get; set; }
    public String filePath { get; set; }
    public Byte[] thumbnail { get; set; }
}

private async void Gener8MapMarkers(List<PhotraxBaseData> _pbd)
{
    foreach (PhotraxBaseData pbd in _pbd)
    {
        String descAndFilename = Path.GetFileName(pbd.filePath);

        if (null != pbd.imgDescription)
        {
            descAndFilename = String.Format("{0} - {1}", pbd.imgDescription, descAndFilename);
        }
        BitmapImage bmi = await PhotraxUtils.ByteArrayToBitmapImage(pbd.thumbnail);
        if (PhotraxUtils.ValidLatAndLong(pbd.latitude, pbd.longitude))
        {
            Location loc = new Location(pbd.latitude, pbd.longitude);
            AddPushpin(loc, descAndFilename, pbd.dateTimeTaken, null, DataLayer);
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(this byte[] byteArray)
{
    // from http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/04/convert-byte-array-to-an-image-in-winrt
    if (byteArray != null)
    {
        using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
            var image = new BitmapImage();
            stream.Seek(0);
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public class PushpinMetadata
{
    public string DescAndFileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeTaken { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Thumbnail { get; set; }
}

public void AddPushpin(Location latlong, string descAndFileName, DateTime dateTimeTaken, BitmapImage thumbnail, MapLayer layer)
{
    Pushpin p = new Pushpin()
    {
        Tag = new PushpinMetadata()
        {
            DescAndFileName = descAndFileName,
            DateTimeTaken = dateTimeTaken,
            Thumbnail = thumbnail
        }
    };

    MapLayer.SetPosition(p, latlong);
    p.Tapped += PinTapped;
    layer.Children.Add(p);
}

private void PinTapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Pushpin p = sender as Pushpin;
    PushpinMetadata m = (PushpinMetadata)p.Tag;

    //Ensure there is content to be displayed
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.DescAndFileName))
    {
        Infobox.DataContext = m;
        Infobox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MapLayer.SetPosition(Infobox, MapLayer.GetPosition(p));
    }
    else
    {
        Infobox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
<bm:Map.Children>
    <!-- Data Layer-->
    <bm:MapLayer Name="DataLayer"/>
    <!--Common Infobox-->
    <bm:MapLayer>
        <Grid x:Name="Infobox" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,-115,-15,0">
            <Border Width="300" Height="110" Background="Black" Opacity="0.8" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5"/>
            <StackPanel Height="100" Margin="5">
                <Grid Height="40">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DescAndFileName}" FontSize="20" Width="250" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Button Content="X" Tapped="CloseInfobox_Tapped" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Height="40">
                    <Viewbox Height="200" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="Both">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Margin="2"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Height="40">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateTimeTaken}" FontSize="16" Width="290" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </bm:MapLayer>
    <callisto:CustomDialog Content="CustomDialog" Height="100" Width="100"/>
</bm:Map.Children>
```

My guess is that the Image's Source property doesn't quite know what to do with the BitmapImage it's bound to via "Thumbnail"; but I don't know how to unbabelize the mismatch (presuming that's where the problem lies).

### UPDATE

To answer Faye's brother Chris, here is the "database" (SQLite class) declaration:

```
public Byte[] thumbnail { get; set; }
```

Here is where I was calling the converter method, passing the appropriate member of the class instance, and then adding a pushpin:

```
BitmapImage bmi = await PhotraxUtils.ByteArrayToBitmapImage(pbd.thumbnail);
if (PhotraxUtils.ValidLatAndLong(pbd.latitude, pbd.longitude))
{
    Location loc = new Location(pbd.latitude, pbd.longitude);
    //AddPushpin(loc, descAndFilename, pbd.dateTimeTaken, null, DataLayer);
    AddPushpin(loc, descAndFilename, pbd.dateTimeTaken, bmi, DataLayer);
}
```

However: **MY BAD, PEOPLES!!!**

I had neglected to replace my placeholder "null" arg with "bmi" (you can see my previous code commented out above, and my new working call to AddPushpin() below it). The image's size/scale is all wrong, but that can be fixed easily enough, I reckon.

I don't know whether to jump for joy or kick myself in the keister, so I think I'll do both simultaneously.

Thanks to Mr. Dunaway for making me look closer at my code - something I obviously should have done before posting.

Comment: A few things to check - make sure the binding works (check output window for binding errors and/or use a debug converter), check if the layout works (it could be there, just 0 size) and check if the `BItmapImage` is there - see if you can display it some other way perhaps.

Comment: Can you show the code where you query the data from the database?  What is the column type in the database?

Comment: @FilipSkakun: I see nothing interesting in the output; I searched for "binding" and "image" and got nothing. As for size, won't the Width and Height="Auto" in the XAML preclude a 0-sized image?

Comment: Please see my Update - pretty much solved.